# Given a BBOX and Zoom Range, Return All TMS Addresses

Tags: python, web-mapping, tile-map-service

Given a bounding box using WGS84 lat long pairs (represented any way, not important to me) and a range of zoom levels, I'd like to be able to generate a CSV representing all standard z/x/y TMS addresses for a web map in a spherical Mercator projection.

For example, given the city of Seattle, with a BBOX of: `(47.75, -122.14), (47.53, -122.53)` and desired zoom levels 12-16, I'd like to see a delimited list something like:

```
z  |  x   |  y
----------------
12 | 656  | 1429
12 | 655  | 1429
...
14 | 2626 | 5724
```

Does anyone know of any way to do this, preferably in Python?

Answer (score 7):

I just came across this Python library by Sean Gillies that makes this easy.

https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile

The following will get you the tile at the specified lng/lat.

```
"""
pip install mercantile
"""
lng, lat, zoom = -122.14, 47.75, 12
print(mercantile.tile(lng, lat, zoom))

# Tile(x=658, y=1428, z=12)
```

The tiles method will get a list of tiles for bounds as you required:

```
bounds = (-122.14, 47.53, -122.53, 47.75)
all_tiles = mercantile.tiles(*bounds, zooms=[3])
for t in all_tiles:
    print t
```

Outputs:

```
Tile(x=0, y=2, z=3)
Tile(x=1, y=2, z=3)
Tile(x=1, y=2, z=3)
Tile(x=2, y=2, z=3)
Tile(x=3, y=2, z=3)
Tile(x=4, y=2, z=3)
Tile(x=5, y=2, z=3)
Tile(x=6, y=2, z=3)
Tile(x=7, y=2, z=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mike Migurski wrote a sweet seeding script for TileStache that does just this: https://github.com/migurski/TileStache/blob/master/scripts/tilestache-seed.py#L89-L90

Found that script after had already extracted the coordinate generate logic from a script written by @tcmw for Development Seed. https://raw.github.com/developmentseed/TileLive/master/tileseed.py Simply piped out the results to STDOUT.